# Finding parameters for which a sequence is dense

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, dynamical-systems, irrational-numbers

I want to find the set of parameters $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence

$$
x_n=(\alpha \lambda^nv)\,\mathrm{mod}\,1
$$
is dense in the unit square $\lbrack 0,1\rbrack^2$ where 
$$
\lambda=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad v=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
One may exploit that $v$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
i.e. $x_n=(A^n(\alpha v))\,\mathrm{mod}\,1$

I'm thankful for any kind of advice.